# Order of evaluation in assignment statements

Tags: ada

The [Ada 2012 standard](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-2.html) says:

> For the execution of an assignment_statement, the variable_name and the expression are first evaluated in an arbitrary order.

I am wondering how far reaching that statement is. If both the right hand side and the left hand side of an assignment contains subprogram calls, can those calls be made in arbitrary order, or will all the left hand side be evaluated before/after all the calls of the right hand side?

E.g. if I have `Arr(L1(X), L2(X)) := Arr(R1(Y), R2(Y))`, can I be sure that the call order will be one of:

1. L1, L2, R1, R2
2. L1, L2, R2, R1
3. L2, L1, R1, R2
4. L2, L1, R2, R1
5. R1, R2, L1, L2
6. R1, R2, L2, L1
7. R2, R1, L1, L2
8. R2, R1, L2, L1

Or could the calls on the left hand side and the right hand side be mixed, such as: L1, R2, L2, R2?

Comment: This is way SPARK, the verified subset of Ada, forbids any side effect in functions (no access to global state and no "in out" parameters). If the order of evaluation cannot be determined, the result will be non-portable or unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can always control the call order in your source code by eliminating shortcuts.

Given your example:

```ada
Arr(L1(X), L2(X)) := Arr(R1(Y), R2(Y))
```

You can specify the order as in the example below forcing the evaluation to be in the order of  R1, R2, L1, L2.

```ada
R1_Index := R1(Y);
R2_Index := R2(Y);
L1_Index := L1(X);
L2_Index := L2(X);
Arr(L1_Index, L2_Index) := Arr(R1_Index, R2_Index);
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But when analyzing code I did not write,  I do not get to pick the order. Hence, the question.

Comment: Since you cannot pick the order and the standard provides no specified order then what is to be gained from the question? If the software works under the current conditions and you do not know the order of evaluation then perhaps the order is not important.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the reading is that it wouldn't mix them and instead use one of your 8 options above.  However, I couldn't find any specific wording to confirm or deny that.  If no one else is able to answer definitively, I would recommend creating an issue at the Ada Rapporteur Group github and seek clarification on the ARM wording.  You might be able to get a more definitive answer there

https://github.com/Ada-Rapporteur-Group/User-Community-Input/issues

Comment: Thanks for there reference to the Ada Rapporteur Group! I have posted the issue there: https://github.com/Ada-Rapporteur-Group/User-Community-Input/issues/89

Comment: @DanielAbrahamsson No problem.  Just make keep in mind a lot of them are from around the world, so answer may not be quick based on when they see it and have time to study the ARM to verify, etc

Answer (score 1):

As long as the functions don't have side effects it should not matter.
Plus, optimizing compilers (GNAT for instance) will certainly do better than calling L1, L2, R1, R2 separately (in any order), if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically interested in the case when they have side effects (i.e., when order matters). Not because I am writing such code, but because I am analyzing arbitrary code which could contain such constructs.

Comment: In this case you could consider tools like CodePeer, AdaControl (https://www.adalog.fr/en/adacontrol.html), Rejuvenation-Ada (https://github.com/TNO/Rejuvenation-Ada), other libadalang-based software or other ASIS-based software. Perhaps one of them is able to catch such cases and emit warnings.

Answer (score 1):

> the variable_name and the expression are first evaluated in an arbitrary order.

This wording means the order is one of

1. The variable_name is evaluated first, then the expression, or
2. The expression is evaluated first, then the variable_name

If the compiler can prove it is equivalent to one of those orders, they may also be evaluated in parallel.